# Analytical approximation of $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} l(x)~\mathbb{1}_{x\geq a}~\mathbb{1}_{x\leq b}~~\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integral

I have an integral where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ but their order is not known and I want to compute

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} l(x)~\mathbb{1}_{x\geq a}~\mathbb{1}_{x\leq b}~~\mathrm{d}x = \mathbb{1}_{b \geq a}~\int_{a}^{b} l(x)~\mathrm{d}x=\mathbb{1}_{b \geq a} (L(b)-L(a))$$

with $L(x)= \int l(x) ~\mathrm{d}x$ and the indicator function $\mathbb{1}_{F} = 1$ if $F$ is true or $\mathbb{1}_{F} = 0$ if $F$ is false. Note that $l(x)$ is sigmoid between 0 and 1, e.g., the logistic function. I would like to replace this expression by one without the indicator function. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Is case format good enough for you?

Comment: No, that's what we have...

Comment: Since you want the answer to be zero when $b\lt a,$ you *must* use something that is the mathematical equivalent of the indicator function.  What is your statistical problem and why does it preclude the notation you are using already?

Comment: whuber Is there maybe an approximation? I would love to replace $\mathbb{1}_{b \geq a}$ by the logistic function but then I get nasty integrals!